# Passing req to EJS as default

Tags: node.js, ejs

So I have a user session middleware that handles current user's session like getting current user's data. In order to use the function inside the EJS file, I have to pass the req variable manually on every render() function and call it like req.get_current_user(). Could I set the req as default data to pass or is there any better practices of my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in express you can set

```js
response.locals.req = req
```

in one of middlewares and use <% req. %> in .ejs files.